# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: php

i have this bunch of code:

```
  $field_with_lengths = array('menu', 'position', 'visible');
  foreach($field_with_lengths as $field_with_lenths => $maxlength){
  if(strlen(trim(mysql_prep($_POST[$fieldname]))) => $maxlength){
  $errors[] = $fieldname;}
```

i'm getting the folowing error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\xampp\htdocs\vp\edit_info.php on line 22

wich is: `if(strlen(trim(mysql_prep($_POST[$fieldname]))) => $maxlength){`

i am not managing to find anything wrong on line 22
how can i fix that up?

Answer (score 1):

It's `>=` (greater than or equal to) not `=>` (equal to or greater than):

```
if(strlen(trim(mysql_prep($_POST[$fieldname]))) >= $maxlength){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strlen(trim(mysql_prep($_POST[$fieldname]))) >= $maxlength){
```

Equal sign must come after the bracket

Comment: For reference => is actually used to assign a value to a specific key when defining an array :)